# Display Mat in PictureBox after crop by four point vector in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-forms-designer

I current do a project to drop the selected area in an image.

I use OpenCV to get Mat area and display it into PictureBox of windows form C++

This is my code cropped correct and display ok in imshow. But when I convert to bitmap and insert in PictureBox it shows error. Sometimes it is ok and I don't know why.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> imagePoints; // This have 4 selected point
Rect r = boundingRect(imagePoints);
Mat imgRoi = cam_view(r);

cv::Point2f src_vertices[4];
src_vertices[0] = imagePoints[0];
src_vertices[1] = imagePoints[1];
src_vertices[2] = imagePoints[2];
src_vertices[3] = imagePoints[3];

cv::Point2f dst_vertices[4];
dst_vertices[0] = cv::Point(0, 0);
dst_vertices[1] = cv::Point(imgRoi.cols - 1, 0);
dst_vertices[2] = cv::Point(imgRoi.cols - 1, imgRoi.rows - 1);
dst_vertices[3] = cv::Point(0, imgRoi.rows - 1);


Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);
cv::Size size(imgRoi.cols, imgRoi.rows);
warpPerspective(cam_view, mat_cropped, warpMatrix, size, INTER_CUBIC, BORDER_CONSTANT);

**//This imshow show correctly image that cropped**
imshow("mat_cropped", mat_cropped);

Mat camview_crop = mat_cropped.clone();
System::IntPtr ptr(camview_crop.ptr());

//This step cause error
Bitmap^ bmpSawMarkRGB = gcnew Bitmap(camview_crop.cols, camview_crop.rows, camview_crop.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
ptbAreaView->Image = bmpSawMarkRGB;
ptbAreaView->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::Normal;
ptbAreaView->Refresh();
delete bmpSawMarkRGB;
```

After run it show error

```
************** 例外テキスト **************
System.ArgumentException:Parameter is not valid。
   場所 System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, PixelFormat format, IntPtr scan0)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: This happened because cv::Mat have it's own reference counter. You should create an MC++ array for image data and copy it from camview_crop.data and size = camview_crop.rows*camview_crop.step (or from camview_crop.databegin to camview_crop.dataend)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure out the solution by change the type in bitmap this
cvtColor(camview_crop, newImage, CV_BGR2BGRA);
  System::IntPtr ptr(newImage.ptr());
  
  Bitmap^ bmpSawMarkRGB = gcnew Bitmap(newImage.cols, newImage.rows, newImage.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppArgb, ptr);